# Why can't I use the mute button when using Airplay as an output device?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, audio, airplay

From my MacBook Pro I send all audio using Airplay to my Airplay Express. I can adjust the volume with the volume buttons (<kbd>F11</kbd> and the <kbd>F12</kbd> keys) but I can't use the mute button on the <kbd>F10</kbd> key. It shows me the following when I press it:

[image]

Why is that? Can I somehow make the mute key work with an Airplay device?